# How to get individually displayed markers on google map that is using clusters?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, markers

I need to get all markers that are individually displayed on my google map.
I'm using clusters so when I zoom the map new markers are individually displayed (those who doesn't fit into any cluster) I need to add a label ( a number ) on each individually marker.

I know that there are methods to get all markers or all markers from specific cluster, but these methods are not going to help me.

Is there any method in order to get those markers?

Comment: Why don't you add the  labels by default and bind the map-property of the labels to the map-property of the related marker(as soon as the marker will be displayed the label will be visible too)

Comment: Any ideea how i can do that? Becouse marker is intialized with new google.maps.Marker() and the label with new MarkerWithLabel({}); ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you use both, Marker and MarkerWithLabel. When you use MarkerWithLabel you only need to create them and add them to the Markerclusterer, there is nothing more to do: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9eecpvou/

Comment: yes, this might be the way i should do. Thanks.